# Does having unused assets in your assets folder affect app size?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have some textures in my assets folder, which I do not use at all in the game/code. Does this still affect the size of the app?

Comment: Yes it does since it will be packaged locally within your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see how it is in eclipse:

firstly the normal asset folder from some trash app with size summary of generated .apk file:

[image: apk without unnecessary files]

then I've added 1MB unnecessary .jpg file that I've nowhere use (just copied into asset folder):

[image: apk with unnecessary 1MB file]

so as we can see in Eclipse unnecessary textures affects apk size as much as their weight is

Comment: what if i put unused files OUTSIDE the android assets folder, like just in the project folder. Will that affect app size?

Comment: @Nahro And can't you just check it? Maybe tell what application you want to make and someone will make it for you.

Comment: @MateuszGaweł thats a great idea. I already posted on reddit and found someone.